# Evaluate T* at the given vector in $C^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an Inner product space V, where $ V= C^2$,
$ T(z_1,z_2) = (2z_1 + iz_2, (1-i)z_1), $
$  x= (3-i, 1+2i). $ I need to evaluate    $T$* at the given vector x in V.
So I did:
$ \lt T( z_1,z_2) ,(3-i, 1 + 2i) \gt = \lt T( 2z_1 + iz_2,(1-i)z_1) ,(3-i, 1 + 2i) \gt$
$= (5z_1-z_2)-i(5z_1 + 3z_2) = \lt ( z_1,z_2) ,T $*$(3-i, 1 + 2i) \gt $ From this,  I get confused about how to deduce $T$*(x) in the case of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose the $T^*x=(w_1,w_2)$.

$$\langle(z_1,z_2),(w_1,w_2)\rangle=z_1w_1^*+z_1w_1^*\\
=(5z_1-z_2)-i(5z_1 + 3z_2)\\
=z_1(5-5i)+z_2(-1-3i).$$

Comment: Then T*(x) = ((5 + 5i), (-1+ 3i)) ! right?

Comment: @Trux Indeed. Quite simple, no? ;)